# How to delete content type from a list using c# and scom

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list, content-type, scom, c-sharp

How can I remove a Content Type from a List ?

I've found code for deleting from sites but not from Lists.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;

namespace CSOMSamples
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //// String Variable to store the siteURL
            string siteURL = "http://c4968397007/";

            //// Get the context for the SharePoint Site to access the data
            ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(siteURL);

            //// Get the custom list by title
            List list = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Custom");

            //// Get the content type by id for the custom list 
            ContentType ct = list.ContentTypes.GetById("0x01003D7B5A54BF843D4381F54AB9D229F98A00823A04B0C30F5747840B1E74FB62285F");

            //// Delete the content type from the list
            ct.DeleteObject();
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

Source: [How to delete the content type from the list using CSOM in SharePoint 2013](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/Blogs/12137/how-to-delete-the-content-type-from-the-list-using-csom-in-s.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using below code

```
SPList list = currentWeb.Lists.TryGetList("ListName");
if (list != null)
{
    SPContentType itemCT = list.ContentTypes["CTName"];
    if (itemCT != null)
    {
        list.ContentTypes.Delete(itemCT.Id);
        list.Update();
    }
}
```